# how mysql innodb record lock and insert intention lock works together?

Tags: mysql

There are many of InnoDB locks instrunction, but in my test, something still confusing me. MySQL version is 5.7 with Repeatable Read isolation level.

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table if not exists t1(id float,name varchar(20),key idx_id(id));
insert into t1 values (1,'a'),(3,'c'), (4,'d'), (10,'f');

-- session1:
START TRANSACTION;
insert into t1 values (5,'a');   

-- session 2:
update t1 set name='a2' where id > 4 and id < 5;   -- wating for lock

-- session3:
update t1 set name='a2' where id > 5 and id < 10; -- no wait,executed.
```

To My understanding, session1 hold insert intention lock (4,10), session2 is waiting for X lock (4,5) so it is blocked by session 1, that is rantional. Session3 could wait for session 1 to release lock, but the truth is session3 just be executed. How this happened?

Comment: _Heheh Small Point_ `where id > 4 and id < 5` which integers are you expecting to occur between 4 and 5 ? _Did mathematics change while i was looking the other way :)_

Comment: InnoDB does Row-level locking (not table level). In session1, you are inserting row with `id = 5`, so any other session trying to access the row with `id = 5` will have to wait for lock release. Now, the query in session3, is skipping that particular row (`id > 5`), so session 3 does not really need to wait for anything.

Comment: If session 1 just have row-level lock row with id=5, why session 2 is waiting

Answer (score 0):

Just after session 1 executes `START TRANSACTION; insert into t1 values (5,'a');`, the output of `select * from performance_schema.data_locks;` is:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID                       | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
+--------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| INNODB | 139675093921992:1063:139675020906192 |                  2117 |        52 |       31 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL       |       139675020906192 | TABLE     | IX        | GRANTED     | NULL      |
+--------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Just after session 2 executes `update t1 set name='a2' where id > 4 and id < 5;`, the output is:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID                        | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA                  |
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| INNODB | 139675093921144:1063:139675020900048  |                  2118 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL       |       139675020900048 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL                       |
| INNODB | 139675093921144:2:5:6:139675020897056 |                  2118 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | idx_id     |       139675020897056 | RECORD    | X             | WAITING     | 0x0000A040, 0x000000000208 |
| INNODB | 139675093921992:1063:139675020906192  |                  2117 |        52 |       31 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL       |       139675020906192 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL                       |
| INNODB | 139675093921992:2:5:6:139675020903280 |                  2117 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | idx_id     |       139675020903280 | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 0x0000A040, 0x000000000208 |
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

After session 3 executes `update t1 set name='a2' where id > 5 and id < 10;`, the output is:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID                        | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME      | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA                  |
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| INNODB | 139675093922840:1063:139675020912224  |                  2119 |        50 |       30 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL            |       139675020912224 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL                       |
| INNODB | 139675093922840:2:5:5:139675020909312 |                  2119 |        50 |       30 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | idx_id          |       139675020909312 | RECORD    | X             | GRANTED     | 0x00002041, 0x000000000203 |
| INNODB | 139675093922840:2:4:5:139675020909656 |                  2119 |        50 |       30 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | GEN_CLUST_INDEX |       139675020909656 | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 0x000000000203             |
| INNODB | 139675093921144:1063:139675020900048  |                  2118 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL            |       139675020900048 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL                       |
| INNODB | 139675093921144:2:5:6:139675020897056 |                  2118 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | idx_id          |       139675020897056 | RECORD    | X             | WAITING     | 0x0000A040, 0x000000000208 |
| INNODB | 139675093921992:1063:139675020906192  |                  2117 |        52 |       31 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | NULL            |       139675020906192 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL                       |
| INNODB | 139675093921992:2:5:6:139675020903280 |                  2117 |        49 |       29 | test          | t1          | NULL           | NULL              | idx_id          |       139675020903280 | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 0x0000A040, 0x000000000208 |
+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

So, the reason why session 2 is blocked is: it requests `next-key lock (4, 5]` which is `(4, 5) gap lock` plus `5 index-record lock`, but session 1 is holding `5 index-record lock`. And the reason why session 3 is not blocked is: it requests `next-key lock (5, 10]` which is `(5, 10) gap lock` plus `10 index-record lock`, and nobody is holding `10 index-record lock`.